# sistema de valoración con estrellas

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel

tengo un problema debo obtener dos tipos de valoraciones distintas con estrellas. estoy trabajando con laravel y javascript.
Aclaro no se mucho de javascript asi que lo que hice fue solo duplicar el codigo  javascript y html. talvez haya una forma de practica de hacerlo pero esta fue la mas sencilla que encontre.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como veran en el codigo esta duplicado solo que con etiquetas diferentes.

```js
const ratingStars = [...document.getElementsByClassName("rating__star")];
const ratingResult = document.querySelector("input[name='stars']");

printRatingResult(ratingResult);

function executeRating(stars, result) {
   const starClassActive = "rating__star fas fa-star";
   const starClassUnactive = "rating__star far fa-star";
   const starsLength = stars.length;
   let i;
   stars.map((star) => {
      star.onclick = () => {
         i = stars.indexOf(star);

         if (star.className.indexOf(starClassUnactive) !== -1) {
            printRatingResult(result, i + 1);
            for (i; i >= 0; --i) stars[i].className = starClassActive;
         } else {
            printRatingResult(result, i);
            for (i; i < starsLength; ++i) stars[i].className = starClassUnactive;
         }
      };
   });
}

function printRatingResult(result, num = 0) {
      result.value = num;
}

executeRating(ratingStars, ratingResult);



const ratingStars2 = [...document.getElementsByClassName("rating__star2")];
const ratingResult2 = document.querySelector("input[name='stars2']");

printRatingResult2(ratingResult2);

function executeRating(stars, result) {
   const starClassActive = "rating__star fas fa-star";
   const starClassUnactive = "rating__star far fa-star";
   const starsLength = stars.length;
   let i;
   stars.map((star) => {
      star.onclick = () => {
         i = stars.indexOf(star);

         if (star.className.indexOf(starClassUnactive) !== -1) {
            printRatingResult2(result, i + 1);
            for (i; i >= 0; --i) stars[i].className = starClassActive;
         } else {
            printRatingResult2(result, i);
            for (i; i < starsLength; ++i) stars[i].className = starClassUnactive;
         }
      };
   });
}

function printRatingResult2(result, num = 0) {
      result.value = num;
}

executeRating(ratingStars2, ratingResult2);
```

```css
@import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css";
.rating {
   position: relative;
   width: 180px;
   background: transparent;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   gap: .3em;
   padding: 5px;
   overflow: hidden;
   border-radius: 20px;
   box-shadow: 0 0 2px #b3acac;
}

.rating__result {
   position: relative;

   z-index: 10;
   font: 3em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   color: #ff0000;
   pointer-events: none;
}

.rating__star {
   font-size: 1.3em;
   cursor: pointer;
   color: #dabd18b2;
   transition: filter linear .3s;
}

.rating__star:hover {
   filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 4px gold);
}

.ratingx {
    position: relative;
    width: 180px;
    background: transparent;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: .3em;
    padding: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px #b3acac;
 }
 
 .rating__resultx {
    position: relative;
 
    z-index: 10;
    font: 3em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #ff0000;
    pointer-events: none;
 }
 
 .rating__starx {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #dabd18b2;
    transition: filter linear .3s;
 }
 
 .rating__starx:hover {
    filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 4px gold);
 }

 .ratinga {
    position: relative;
    width: 180px;
    background: transparent;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: .3em;
    padding: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px #b3acac;
 }
 
 .rating__resulta {
    position: relative;
 
    z-index: 10;
    font: 3em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #ff0000;
    pointer-events: none;
 }
 
 .rating__stara {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #dabd18b2;
    transition: filter linear .3s;
 }
 
 .rating__stara:hover {
    filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 4px gold);
 }
```

```html
<div class="rating">

         <i class="rating__star far fa-star"></i>
         <i class="rating__star far fa-star"></i>
         <i class="rating__star far fa-star"></i>
         <i class="rating__star far fa-star"></i>
         <i class="rating__star far fa-star"></i>
      </div>
<br>
      <input type="text" name="stars" class="rating__result">
    <br>
   
</div> 

<hr>


<div class="rating">

         <i class="rating__star far fa-star"></i>
         <i class="rating__star far fa-star"></i>
         <i class="rating__star far fa-star"></i>
         <i class="rating__star far fa-star"></i>
         <i class="rating__star far fa-star"></i>
      </div>
<br>
      <input type="text" name="stars2" class="rating__result2">
    <br>
    <br>
      <button type="submit">Send Stars</button>
</div>
```

Al marcar las estrellas en ambos contenedores suma solo en el primer input
y el segundo input queda en 0.

alguna forma de solucionar esto?.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al duplicar las etiquetas dejaste algunas con el nombre de la clase original, por lo que al intentar manipular el segundo conjunto, en realidad es como si metieras 5 estrellas más en el primer grupo. De paso, fíjate que usaste el mismo nombre para la función `executeRating`.

Me tomé la libertad de modificar un poco la estructura de tu HTML, dejando dos contenedores (con clase `.rating_container`) y, en cada uno, un grupo de estrellas y el respectivo input. Mi intención es separar el problema original en 2 problemas más pequeños sin tener que preocuparme por un eventual acoplamiento (o conflicto) entre ellos.

Iterando sobre todos los contenedores con la clase `.rating_container` utilizo en cada uno tu misma función `executeRating`, pero dentro de ésta *mis selectores están acotados al contenedor y no al documento*, por lo cual no tengo que andar cambiando la clase para diferenciar el input de destino.

El resto es básicamente tu código. Cabe notar que, como los inputs se llaman distinto, usé un selector parcial

```
  const result = container.querySelector('input[name^="stars"]')
```

que significa: "elemento cuyo nombre empieza con 'stars'". Dentro de cada contenedor ese selector tiene un solo resultado.

```js
function printRatingResult(result, num = 0) {
  result.value = num;
}


function executeRating(container) {

  const result = container.querySelector('input[name^="stars"]'),
    stars = Array.from(container.querySelectorAll('.rating__star'));

  printRatingResult(result);
  const starClassActive = "rating__star fas fa-star";
  const starClassUnactive = "rating__star far fa-star";
  const starsLength = stars.length;

  stars.map((star, i) => {
    star.onclick = () => {

      if (star.className.indexOf(starClassUnactive) !== -1) {
        printRatingResult(result, i + 1);
        for (i; i >= 0; --i) stars[i].className = starClassActive;
      } else {
        printRatingResult(result, i);
        for (i; i < starsLength; ++i) stars[i].className = starClassUnactive;
      }
    };
  });
}


Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.rating_container')).forEach(container => {
  executeRating(container);
})
```

```css
@import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css";
.rating {
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  background: transparent;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: .3em;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #b3acac;
}

.rating_container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: space-around;
}


.rating__result {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  font: 3em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #ff0000;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.rating__star {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #dabd18b2;
  transition: filter linear .3s;
}

.rating__star:hover {
  filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 4px gold);
}
```

```html
<div class="rating_container">
  <div class="rating">

    <i class="rating__star far fa-star"></i>
    <i class="rating__star far fa-star"></i>
    <i class="rating__star far fa-star"></i>
    <i class="rating__star far fa-star"></i>
    <i class="rating__star far fa-star"></i>
  </div>

  <input type="text" name="stars" class="rating__result">
  <br>

</div>

<hr>

<div class="rating_container">

  <div class="rating">

    <i class="rating__star far fa-star"></i>
    <i class="rating__star far fa-star"></i>
    <i class="rating__star far fa-star"></i>
    <i class="rating__star far fa-star"></i>
    <i class="rating__star far fa-star"></i>
  </div>

  <input type="text" name="stars2" class="rating__result">
</div>
```